# Discord bot for ordering food

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JavaScript, and I made a [Discord](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discord_(software)) bot using [discord.js](https://discord.js.org/) that serves food and drinks and replies without the need of a prefix. My issue is that I want to try cleaning up the code and get rid of all the if-statements, but I don't know how to do so.

```
bot.on("message", message => {
  const reply = [
    "Here's your order!",
    "Enjoy!",
    "Here you go!",
    "Let me know if you need anything else!",
    "You've been served.",
    "That'll be $3.50.",
    "That'll be $5.50", 
  ];
  const response = reply[Math.floor(Math.random() * reply.length)];
  
  if (message.content.toLowerCase().includes("order coffee")) {
    message.channel.send("Coming right up!").then(msg => {
    msg.delete({ timeout: 5000 })
  })
  .catch(console.error);
    setTimeout(function(){
      message.reply(response);
      message.channel.send("https://cdn.glitch.com/1f3ad41e-6c0c-4160-902b-a50330e419bd%2FCoffee%20cropped.gif?v=1613444146008");
    }, 5000);
  }  
  
  if (message.content.toLowerCase().includes("order latte")) {
    message.channel.send("Coming right up!").then(msg => {
    msg.delete({ timeout: 5000 })
  })
  .catch(console.error);
    setTimeout(function(){
      message.reply(response);
      message.channel.send("https://cdn.glitch.com/1f3ad41e-6c0c-4160-902b-a50330e419bd%2FLatte.gif?v=1613444145762");
    }, 5000);
  }
  
  if (message.content.toLowerCase().includes("order muffin")) {
    message.channel.send("Coming right up!").then(msg => {
    msg.delete({ timeout: 5000 })
  })
  .catch(console.error);
    setTimeout(function(){
      message.reply(response);
      message.channel.send("https://cdn.glitch.com/1f3ad41e-6c0c-4160-902b-a50330e419bd%2FMuffin.gif?v=1613444146225");
    }, 5000);
  }
  
  if (message.content.toLowerCase().includes("order strawberry cake roll")) {
    message.channel.send("Coming right up!").then(msg => {
    msg.delete({ timeout: 5000 })
  })
  .catch(console.error);
    setTimeout(function(){
      message.reply(response);
      message.channel.send("https://cdn.glitch.com/1f3ad41e-6c0c-4160-902b-a50330e419bd%2FStrawberry%20cake%20roll.gif?v=1613444145762");
    }, 5000);
  }
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, is too general to be useful here. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state the task accomplished by the code. Please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as  [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436/120114) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Comment: Hey Joseph. It looks like the only things that are different are: the message content check and the gif you are returning. Maybe you could get rid of the if's all together and have an object that contains key value pairs? Like `const gifs = { coffee: "link to coffee gif" }` and then `map` through the gifs and match the key to the message content and send the associated value? If that isn't clear I can post an answer.

Comment: @BensSteves could you show an example? I am not sure on how to do it.

Comment: @JosephLee Posted my thoughts on it. Looks like Zsolt beat me to it but his solution looks good as well

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I [changed the title](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/256114/revisions) so that it describes what the code does per [site goals](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask): "_State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it._". Feel free to [edit] and give it a different title if there is something more appropriate.

Answer (score 14):

The first thing to look at is: what is the same for each if statement and what is different. The key differences are:

```javascript
message.content.toLowerCase().includes("this string here is what's different")
```

and

```javascript
message.channel.send("links are different")
```

To clean it up, we can get rid of the if statements all together and create an object that contains key:value pairs with key `message.content` you want to check against with and value the associated media link. That would look like this:

```javascript
const gifs = { 
  "coffee": "https://cdn.glitch.com/1f3ad41e-6c0c-4160-902b-a50330e419bd%2FCoffee%20cropped.gif?v=1613444146008", 
  "latte": "https://cdn.glitch.com/1f3ad41e-6c0c-4160-902b-a50330e419bd%2FLatte.gif?v=1613444145762",
  "muffin": "https://cdn.glitch.com/1f3ad41e-6c0c-4160-902b-a50330e419bd%2FMuffin.gif?v=1613444146225",
  "strawberry cake roll": "https://cdn.glitch.com/1f3ad41e-6c0c-4160-902b-a50330e419bd%2FStrawberry%20cake%20roll.gif?v=1613444145762", 
};
```

We can take out the string "order" because that is also common to all of the keys. If the data you are getting back requires you to check on "order coffee" then change it back.

Now you can map through the keys of the `gifs` object to see if that `key` is included in the message content. If it is, return the `value` associated with that key.

```javascript
Object.keys(gifs).forEach(key => { 
  if(message.content.toLowerCase().includes(key)) {
    return gifs[key]; // get the value at key in the gifs object
  }
}
```

`Object.keys()` takes an object and returns an array of the keys in that object. `_.forEach` is a method on an **Array** that loops through an array just like a for loop. It takes a callback function as a param.

Putting that all together we get:

```javascript
// can define this in a helper / util file or at the top of this file since it is a constant list
const REPLIES_LIST = [
    "Here's your order!",
    "Enjoy!",
    "Here you go!",
    "Let me know if you need anything else!",
    "You've been served.",
    "That'll be $3.50.",
    "That'll be $5.50", 
];

bot.on("message", message => { 
  const { channel, content, reply: messageReply} = message; // destructure variables off of message, reply: messageReply renames reply to messageReply
  const response = REPLIES_LIST[Math.floor(Math.random() * REPLIES_LIST.length)];

  Object.keys(gifs).map(key => { 
   if(content.toLowerCase().includes(key)) {
    channel.send("Coming right up!").then(msg => {
      msg.delete({ timeout: 5000 })
    }).catch(console.error);

     setTimeout(() => {
      messageReply(response);
      channel.send(gifs[key]); // get the value at key in the gifs object
    }, 5000);
   }
  });
});
```

**Code Walkthrough**

1. The bot gets a message "message" we declare temporary variables equal to message.content, message.channel, and message.reply by destructuring
2. Create another variable equal to a random response from the reply list or array
3. Traverse through the keys in the `gifs` object using `forEach`
4. For each item in the gifs object we check to see if the `message.content.toLowerCase()` includes that key, if it does we send a message "Coming right up!" to the channel
5. Handle some logic and a catch after sending
6. Create a setTimeout that waits 5 seconds before replying with the response and `channel.send`ing the gif url

#### Updated: 02/17/21

There were comments questioning the use of `_.map` over `_.forEach` or `_.some`. We should be using `_.forEach` in this case and I updated the original answer to reflect that. Below I highlighted the differences between the three and ultimately what works best for this scenario.

**`Array.prototype.map((item) => // do something)`**
A method that iterates through every element of an array and returns a **new array** resulting from the callback function you passed.

Example:

```javascript
 const list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
 const newList = list.map((item) => item + 2); // [1+2, 2+2, 3+2, 4+2, 5+2]

 console.log(list); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
 console.log(newList); // [3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

We only use map if we are using the array that the map returns (in this example `newList`. In the original answer, we were using map *without* returning anything or using the returned array which is an **anit-pattern**.

**`Array.prototype.forEach((item) => // do something)`**
A method that iterates through an array and uses a callback to **mutate** the array, returning **undefined**.

Example:

```javascript
 const list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
 list.forEach((item, index, arr) => arr[index] = item + 2);
 
 console.log(list); //[3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

The `forEach` provides you with the current item (item), index of the current item in the array (index), and the original array (arr).

We use `forEach` when we want to use the callback passed to mutate the array without returning a new array. Key thing to note, you cannot exit a `forEach` without raising an exception.

**`Array.prototype.some((item) => // do something)`**
A method that checks if at **least one element** in the array "passes" the callback you provide, returning a **boolean**.

Example:

```javascript
 const list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
 list.some((item) => item === 2); // true, stops when it reads 2 in the array because it matches
 
 console.log(list); //[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

For the question that was asked, `forEach` is most appropriate. You then have to contemplate, will my data have duplicates or not have anything at all and handle those conditions. If you will have duplicates, you may want to you the `find` method approach Daniël van den Berg suggests. `find` is similar to `forEach` and `some`. It looks for the **first** item that matches the condition and returns that item.

Comment: Any reason you chose map instead of ```forEach```, or even ```some```?

Comment: You could also distill `const cdnSrc = https://cdn.glitch.com/1f3ad41e-6c0c-4160-902b-a50330e419bd%2F` (possibly replace the `%2f` with `/`) to increase readability of GIFS

Comment: A beautiful example of how [Configure, Don't Integrate](https://flylib.com/books/en/1.315.1.53/1/) can improve readability, reduce duplication etc!

Comment: Map is my react framework mind showing up :). `forEach` is more appropriate. Or you can use find like @DaniëlvandenBerg suggested. And I think `some` returns a boolean. Which is fine but you would have to update the code to handle true/false from `some`.

Comment: Please edit your answer to actually use `forEach` or `find`; comments are designed to be temporary and optional reading. And since this is a learning site, it's good to put your best foot forward! Note that performing side-effects in `map` is actually *opposed* to the React mindset - that's what `forEach` is for, after all.

Comment: @TheRubberDuck Yea I was updating my answer to reflect the change. Takes some time to update the answer after posting the comment :). And map is not opposed to the React mindset. You use it quite often actually. Depends on what you are doing and trying to solve :)

Comment: Whoops! saw that the original comment was 8 hours ago and for some reason assumed your reply was also from that long ago. Sorry about that. Also, I don't mean general `map` usage but rather **side-effects** in a mapper function - `map` usage should compute a value, not change one. It's like making an API call in a component render function - you should move that code to `useEffect`, an event handler, or some lifecycle method.

Comment: Your forEach example seems incorrect. forEach will not mutate the list, no matter how hard I try. not even if I do item += 2.

Comment: Great catch @DaniëlvandenBerg. The way I had it you weren't actually updating the array value with `item + 2`. You have to reassign the array item by getting the current index and updating. `arr[index] = item + 2`. Updated the answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 7):

Althrough I mostly agree with Ben Stevens' answer, I do think there is room for even more improvement.

```
// can define this in a helper / util file or at the top of this file since it is a constant list
const REPLIES_LIST = [
    "Here's your order!",
    "Enjoy!",
    "Here you go!",
    "Let me know if you need anything else!",
    "You've been served.",
    "That'll be $3.50.",
    "That'll be $5.50", 
];

bot.on("message", message => { 
  const { channel, content, reply: messageReply} = message; // destructure variables off of message, reply: messageReply renames reply to messageReply
  const response = REPLIES_LIST[Math.floor(Math.random() * REPLIES_LIST.length)];

  const key = Object.keys(gifs).find(key=>content.toLowerCase().includes(key));
  if (!key){
      //Potentially send a "I did not understand you."
      return;
  }
  channel
    .send("Coming right up!")
    .then(msg => {msg.delete({ timeout: 5000 })})
    .catch(console.error);
    
  setTimeout(() => {
    messageReply(response);
    channel.send(gifs[key]); // get the value at key in the gifs object
  }, 5000);
});
```

I changed from using Object.keys(gifs).map to .find. The reason for using find here is that it stops after finding the first occurrence. This ensures that your script won't send two replies if someone puts "order coffee order latte".

Another advantage is that you have less indentation, as the sending of the message is not inside a lambda (one of those "sub-functions", `()=>{}`). This adds some readability.

If you would want to send two messages if someone says `order coffee order latte` you can use the code as Ben Stevens provides, but I would use `.forEach` instead of `.map`. `.map` is intended to return a (modified) copy of the array, which doesn't fit your use-case.

Answer (score 3):

As most of the content is the same in your if statements, you need to check what's changing. It seems it's the image URL only.

You can update the if statement to only change the image URL and send it in the end:

```js
let img = '';
let text = message.content.toLowerCase();

if (text.includes('order coffee')) {
  img = 'https://cdn.glitch.com/1f3ad41e-6c0c-4160-902b-a50330e419bd%2FCoffee%20cropped.gif?v=1613444146008';
}

if (text.includes('order latte')) {
  img = 'https://cdn.glitch.com/1f3ad41e-6c0c-4160-902b-a50330e419bd%2FLatte.gif?v=1613444145762';
}

if (text.includes('order muffin')) {
  img = 'https://cdn.glitch.com/1f3ad41e-6c0c-4160-902b-a50330e419bd%2FMuffin.gif?v=1613444146225';
}

//...

message.channel
  .send('Coming right up!')
  .then((msg) => {
    msg.delete({ timeout: 5000 });
  })
  .catch(console.error);
setTimeout(function () {
  message.reply(response);
  message.channel.send(img);
}, 5000);
```

You could also create an object where the keys are search strings and the values are the image URLs. Maybe you could also create a util function that finds the image by search string:

````js
function findImage(text, images) {
  for (let [query, url] of Object.entries(images)) {
    if (text.toLowerCase().includes(query)) return url;
  }
}

bot.on('message', (message) => {
  const reply = [
    "Here's your order!",
    'Enjoy!',
    'Here you go!',
    'Let me know if you need anything else!',
    "You've been served.",
    "That'll be $3.50.",
    "That'll be $5.50",
  ];
  const images = {
    'order coffee': 'https://cdn.glitch.com/1f3ad41e-6c0c-4160-902b-a50330e419bd%2FCoffee%20cropped.gif?v=1613444146008',
    'order latte': 'https://cdn.glitch.com/1f3ad41e-6c0c-4160-902b-a50330e419bd%2FLatte.gif?v=1613444145762',
    'order muffin': 'https://cdn.glitch.com/1f3ad41e-6c0c-4160-902b-a50330e419bd%2FMuffin.gif?v=1613444146225',
    'order strawberry cake roll': 'https://cdn.glitch.com/1f3ad41e-6c0c-4160-902b-a50330e419bd%2FStrawberry%20cake%20roll.gif?v=1613444145762',
  };
  const response = reply[Math.floor(Math.random() * reply.length)];
  const img = findImage(message.content, images);

  if (!img) { /* return? */ }

  message.channel
    .send('Coming right up!')
    .then((msg) => msg.delete({ timeout: 5000 }))
    .catch(console.error);

  setTimeout(function () {
    message.reply(response);
    message.channel.send(img);
  }, 5000);
});
```
````